# Change locale at runtime in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on a rails 3 app which has different languages in my locales folder. The files are en.yml, pu.yml, sp.yml. All languages have to be converted to their various format and I need help in making users chose any language of their choice with a link like

```
<%= link_to "English language", ...%> <%= link_to "spanish", ...%>
```

When a user choses a language, the language is set as the user's preferred language so that the user does not have to keep selecting a language after each login.

Comment: You can read How-to in the rails guides. There are good description how you can do that kind of thing with a different approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to ream88's answer:

```
<%= link_to "spanish", :controller => 'locale', :action => 'set', :id => 'es' %>
```

In the LocaleController (or any other controller)

```
def set
  locale = params[:id]
  raise 'unsupported locale' unless ['es', 'en', ... ].include?(locale)
  current_user.locale = locale
  current_user.save
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Answer (score 18):

Just add a `locale` string attribute to your `User` model, and make a `before_filter` in your `application_controller.rb` like so:

```
before_filter :set_locale
...
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = current_user.locale if current_user
end
```

More infos at [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)!